# Using Google's OpenID Connect as part of a SSO

Tags: authentication, openid, single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-openid

I'm developing a common auth service for several different web services. The general idea is that a user goes to one of these web services and clicks on a login button and gets redirected to my auth service. Once authenticated, the auth service redirects the user back to the original web service.

To begin with, the auth service will use Google's OpenID Connect service. One idea I had was that when a user was authenticated using Google I could pass around the resulting JWT to other services to use as an auth token. Google mentions this idea in their documentation (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken):

> One thing that makes ID tokens useful is that fact that you can pass them around different components of your app. This can be helpful because different components of your application may pass the ID token between them and use it as a lightweight authentication mechanism authenticating the app and the user.

Can anyone help me with the actual details on how this should work e.g. How do I handle log outs both on Google and from the auth service? There appeared to be some documentation on this in older OpenID Connect Session documents (-03) but it appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass the ID Token that you receive to Google back to the app to use as an auth token. The ID Token will have an audience specific to your app, not the ultimate client.

If you just passed this back to clientA, then you would open it up to auth attacks where clientB could obtain an Google ID Token via your auth service and then use that token to gain access to user data in clientA.

A much better approach would be to mint your own ID Token and provide an audience designation for each app that uses your service.

Monitoring session state is not as straightforward. The easiest thing to do is for your service to wrap G+ sign-in libraries and interface with the session state api's.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/session-state

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I could do the G+ login on the SSO and then do something similar to what Zendesk do for SSO to connect all the internal services. For single sign-out I could then do something similar to what is recommended for OpenID Connect and have services connected via iframes to communicate state.